# Backwards proof for balanced Wheatstone bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, electronics, batteries

[image: schematic]

We know that in this Wheatstone bridge if,
 **$\bf{I_3 = 0}$**, it can be [derived](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge#Derivation) that **$\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}$** . But could we prove it backwards, mathematicaly, that - if in such a circuit **$\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}$**, then it will be also true that **$\bf{I_3 = 0}$**?

I am asking this question because I've seen in the case of solving such circuit problems this argument being made using the reference of Wheatstone bridge, that as $\bf{\frac{R_1}{R_5}=\frac{R_2}{R_4}}$, so the equivalent **$\bf{I_3}$** would be **0**.

Comment: You're dealing with a linear circuit, so yes, the two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @QtizedQ Sorry, I don't think I understand what a linear circuit is. But as you said, in this circuit the two statements are equivalent; so, can we mathematicaly prove the other?

Comment: I'll write up a proof when I get to work. But if you assume those ratios of resistances and solve the circuit, what potential would you get out?

Answer (score 1):

Remove $R_3$ and determine the open circuit voltage $V_3^\mathrm{oc}$ across the diagonal of the bridge (positive on the left node),

$$\begin{align}V_3^\mathrm{oc} &= \left(\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}-\frac{R_5}{R_5+R_1}\right)V \\ &= \frac{R_1R_4-R_2R_5}{(R_2+R_4)(R_1+R_5)}V \\ &= \frac{R_1/R_5-R_2/R_4}{(1+R_2/R_4)(1+R_1/R_5)}V \end{align}$$

From Thévenin's theorem, the current $I_3$ is proportional to $V_3^\mathrm{oc}$, and from the above equation this voltage is zero if and only if the numerator is zero, that is,

$$\frac{R_1}{R_5} = \frac{R_2}{R_4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V_A$ be the voltage at the left node of $R_3$, and let $V_B$ be the node voltage to the right of $R_3$. Let $V_3 = V_A-V_B$ be the voltage across $R_3$. Now, we want to solve for $V_3$ as a function of the source voltage $V_S$ and the resistors $R_i$. We have two independent unknowns to solve for ($V_A$ and $V_3$ full determine $V_B$), so we can write down KCL at the $A$ and $B$ nodes in terms of $V_A,V_3$ and constants to determine the two voltages.

First, we have the KCL at the left node:

$$\frac{V_S-V_A}{R_2} = \frac{V_3}{R_3} + \frac{V_A}{R_4}$$

And then the right node, using $V_B=V_A-V_3$:

$$\frac{V_S-(V_A-V_3)}{R_1} + \frac{V_3}{R_3} = \frac{V_A-V_3}{R_5}$$

Solving these equations using your favorite technique, we find

$$V_3 = \frac{R_3V_S(R_1R_4-R_2R_5)}{...}$$

where I have omitted the denominator, which is a sum of products of three-resistor combinations.

This also tells us that $I_3 = \frac{V_3}{R_3} = \frac{V_S(R_1R_4-R_2R_4)}{...}$

Note that the numerator tells us everything we need. Taking $R_1R_4=R_2R_5$, or similarly $\frac{R_1}{R_5} = \frac{R_2}{R_4}$ assuming nonzero resistors, we see that this makes the numerator zero, which means that the voltage $I_3$ is also zero.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But in the first step of your proof, you used the relation of voltage at a potential divider to the total input voltage and the resistors, that ( $V_{out} = \frac{R2}{R1+R2}V_{in}$}. But this relation requires the current through the potential divider to be zero. [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#General_case) So, in order to make the first statement in your proof true, don't we again have to make the assumption that current flowing through the potential divider is zero, first?

Comment: I'll redo it now that you've revised the circuit so the central element is a resistor.

Comment: I have updated my answer assuming that the central element is a resistor and derived the result that $I_3$ is zero if the resistors obey that specific ratio.

Comment: Are you sure that solving the two equations gives that in the numerator?  How did you get that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to picture this is to model the circuit with $R_3$ removed. Then each side of the bridge is just a simple voltage divider, with voltages at the center of $$V\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}=V\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_4}\right)^{-1}$$ and $$V\frac{R_5}{R_1+R_5}=V\left(1+\frac{R_1}{R_5}\right)^{-1}$$ respectively.

These two voltages are equal if (and only if, assuming V is non-zero) $\frac{R_2}{R_4}=\frac{R_1}{R_5}$.

Since these voltages are equal, adding a resistor (or a wire/capacitor/inductor: basically anything except a current or voltage source) between these two nodes does not change anything: no current flows through the additional circuit element.